# Is there a way to only Export certain wiki pages inside a Pages library using the Export-SPWeb

Tags: 2013, powershell, administration, export

I usually export list and libraries using the following command:-

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://frontend2/commercial/" -ItemUrl "Pages" -Path "c:\exportfile.cmp"     -nofilecompression  -IncludeVersions All -IncludeUserSecurity -Force -Verbose
```

which will export all the pages inside a library named "Pages". but my question is if i can only export certain pages, for example to define a query (using CAML or using Powershell) , to only export wiki pages which have a site column named "Type" = "Policies" ??

if this is not possible using `Export-SPWeb` command,then how i can export certain wiki pages from my Pages library ? and then to import them inside another farm ??

Comment: Seems like you would need to export and import the entire list and just delete the pages that you don't want to keep.

Comment: @Mike hi Mke, thanks for the comment... the problem i have around 2500 wiki pages and i only need to export/import 50 wiki pages... now export 2500 wiki pages will created a file of around 2.5 GB, then i need to move it to another farm and do the import operation... so i am not sure if there is a more reliable way to just export the related 50 wiki pages which have there "Type" = "Policies"?? is this possible as per ur knowledge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another similar way is to export/import the library, to clone it to another "staging" library, use powershell to delete all the items where Type != Policies, then export that library and move it to another farm.

Like this:

```
$web = get-spweb http://sharepoint/subsite
$list = $web.Lists["Cloned Document Library Name "]
$items = $list.Items | ? {$_["Type"] -ne "Policies"}
$items.Count #make sure you have the right number
$items | %{

$_.Delete();

}
```

Then export and import that library to the second farm.

Comment: yes should work, but i was searching if export only the intended pages from the beginning...

Comment: There is no such process with Export-SPWeb I'm afraid